# Trouble trying to get the Duration since newest review using ( dt.date.today() - newest google review),

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df_test = df_all.copy()

df_test['measure'] = df_test['newest_review_date'].str.split().str[0].replace('an', 1).replace('Not', 0).astype(int)
df_test['value'] = df_test['newest_review_date'].str.split().str[1]

df_test['review_date_exact'] = df_test.apply(lambda x: x.date_now - relativedelta(seconds = x.measure) if "second" in x.value else
                                             (x.date_now - relativedelta(minutes = x.measure) if "min" in x.value else
                                             (x.date_now - relativedelta(hours = x.measure) if "hour" in x.value else
                                             (x.date_now - relativedelta(days = x.measure) if "day" in x.value else
                                             (x.date_now - relativedelta(weeks = x.measure) if "week" in x.value else
                                             (x.date_now - relativedelta(months = x.measure) if "month" in x.value else
                                             (x.date_now - relativedelta(years = x.measure) if "year" in x.value else dt.datetime(1990,1,1,) )))))), axis = 1)

df_test['duration'] = df_test.apply(lambda x : abs( (pd.to_datetime(dt.date.today()) - x['review_date_exact']).days ) , axis=1)

df_test
```

The code works for the most part, if a review was posted an hour ago it will correctly categorise the duration as "1 day" but if the review was posted 18 hours ago for some reason it doesn't fall under the duration "1" and shows 0 day instead.

Example of the output in the last column 'duration':

[image: figure 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `dt.date.today()` you get the datetime at midnight, rather than now. So the duration is the duration since midnight. Use `datetime.now()` instead to get the time (or use a datetime value for 'now' from whenever you want the relative value to be from)

Comment: thank you for the insight! It works well after changing it to datetime.now()